# How to delete the uploaded file

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have got a task to upload a file.There is a remove button with this file.If you want to remove,we can press remove button.For that I used the code

The code is

```
<div id="main">
    <p id="addfile1">Add File</p>
    <div id="file1">
        <input type="file"/>
    <input type="image" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7153/6852073179_00961ba267.jpg" width="20px" id="btnClose1"/>
    </div>
    <p id="addfile2">Add File</p>
    <div id="file2">
        <input type="file"/>
    <input type="image" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7153/6852073179_00961ba267.jpg" width="20px" id="btnClose2"/>
    </div>
    <p id="addfile3">Add File</p>
    <div id="file3">
        <input type="file"/>
    <input type="image" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7153/6852073179_00961ba267.jpg" width="20px" id="btnClose3"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

js is

```
$("#file").hide();
 $("#btnClose").hide();
    $("#addfile").click(function() {
        $("#file").show();
        $("#btnClose").show();
        $("#addfile").hide();
});
});
```

[I want to display the file tag by only clicking addfile.When I select a record I want to show a remove button also addfile must be hidden]

[+++DEMO+++](http://jsfiddle.net/8Akuz/3/)

Comment: What do you mean by: "But its not working properly"

Comment: you want to remove the file from the server or cancel the file select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deselect the file you have to clear the value of the input

```
$('input[type="image"]').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('input[type="file"]').val('');
});
```

Where `$('input[type="image"]')` is your cancel image and `('input[type="file"]')` if your `file input`

Comment: @Spokey-its okey.But i must return to add file

Comment: come to chat please i need a help

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
<p id="deletefile1" class="delete">delete File</p>
```

using

```
$(".deletefile").click(function() {
  $("#addfile"+this.id.replace("deletefile","")).hide();
  $.post("pathToJsp",{filetodelete:$(this).data("filename")}, function(data) {
    $("#responseContainer").html(data);
  });
});
```